# RMA:Create Shipping Label: Error " No authorised items or allowed shipping method"

Tags: sales-order, magento2.2.4, rma

When trying to create shipping label while processing RMA giving an error "" No authorised items or allowed shipping method"

Steps to reproduce the error:
  1.Place an order (with any other non free shipping method)
  2.Process it to the complete state
  3.Create RMA for the order and authorize item(s).
  4.Click Create Shipping label at the admin RMA screen.

.